# How to contain image within a container with rounded corners?

Tags: html, css, image

I have this image which is inside a div container. As you can see, the image itself is not showing completely as part of the image stays hidden due to the border-radius which makes it a circle. Is there a way to show this hidden part? I am currently using `object-fit:cover` but this does not help

[image: here]

Comment: how does it look when you use `object-fit: contain` ? But I think you will have to create a second element inside the circle which then holds the image, since there is no way for the browser to know that something is cut off via border-radius.

Comment: ```<img style="object-fit:cover; border-radius:100%;border:1px solid red;"
    src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="400" height="400">``` you can try something like this.

Comment: To get the optimum fit, that is for your img to use as much of the area of the circle as possible, you will have to do a calculation which depends on the image's aspect ratio. This probably means a couple of lines of Javascript, is this acceptable?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, this is acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've rounded off the corners, the original div's bounding-box still includes the corners -- so if you expand the image to fit within the div, it will expand past the rounded corners.

A perfect square circumscribed by a perfect circle will always be 2/3rds the size of the circle. You can define an inner div (the square) and an outer div (the circle). Then you can set your image to be contained within the inner square -- this will work even for non-square images.

```css
.outer {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #aaa;
}

.inner {
  width: 66.66%;
  height: 66.66%;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/300/300');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To optimise the space used within the circle we need to look at the aspect ratio of the image. For example a long but not very high image should take as much of the width of the circle as it can.

This snippet reads the natural width and height of an image and calculates whether the x or y direction is the one to fit into the maximum possible. It does this by remembering that the diameter of a circle that fits a rectangle is the same as the diameter of the rectangle (and vv).

Here's what we get if the aspect ratio is greater than 1:
[image]

Here's what we get if the ratio is less than 1:
[image]

```js
function scale() {
  const img = document.querySelector('.img');
  const w = img.naturalWidth;
  const h = img.naturalHeight;
  const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
  let sizex = 'auto';
  let sizey = 'auto';

  let scale = circle.offsetWidth / Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h);
  if (w / h > 1) {
    sizex = w * scale + 'px';
  } else {
    sizey = h * scale + 'px';
  }
  circle.style.setProperty('--sizex', sizex);
  circle.style.setProperty('--sizey', sizey);
}
window.onload = scale;
window.onresize = scale;
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vmin;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vmin;
  left: 20vmin;
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/400);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: var(--sizex) var(--sizey);
  background-color: white;
}

.img {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/400" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

The snippet is a bit basic, for example if you know the dimensions in advance you could get CSS to do the calculations and not need to load the img just to find its natural width/height.